# FullCalendar - Only display 'allDay' slot when in agenda view (weekly or daily)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

My application only deals in full day events, so I'd like to be able to only display the allDay section for agendaViews. See screen shot below. I want to hide the areas highlighted in red.

Calendar widget: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Screens:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You overcomplicated it. Check the basicViews, http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/basic-views.html and have your events only with start date

```
{
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use "basicWeek" and "basicDay" view,

```
$('#myCaledarId').fullCalendar({
      header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In upper version than V3 like V4, V5, "basicWeek" and "basicDay" has renamed to "dayGridWeek" and "dayGridDay" [Upgrade info](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3)