# How to create jQuery calendar with only week view, without hours component?

Tags: jquery

I was using primefaces schedule to crate my event application, but prime faces doesnt support custom views and their default views are not suited for my needs, I start for searching jQuery solution but all I have found look like this.

I am using fullCalendar plugin, http://jsfiddle.net/qe53etk5/ ,

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        editable: true,

    });
});
```

[image]

But I cant get a week only to view **one week (from monday to monday) without time (days and hours) component!**

And I need something only to display a week, something like this, so basically I need only to view one week, not whole month.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ , you can use the "basicWeek" view:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'basicWeek',
  [...]
});
```

Or, if you still want PrimeFaces:

```
<p:schedule view="basicWeek" [...] >
```

Then, you may want to add events with only start date (see: [FullCalendar - Only display 'allDay' slot when in agenda view (weekly or daily)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044618/fullcalendar-only-display-allday-slot-when-in-agenda-view-weekly-or-daily)):

```
{
  title: 'All Day Event',
  start: new Date(y, m, d)
}
```

Or create allDay events with PrimeFaces:

```
defaultScheduleEvent.setAllDay(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add SlotDuration property to 24 hours

something like this-

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        slotDuration:'24:00'
        //rest of code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using the FullCalendar plugin, right?

When initializing it you can specify that you don't want those [header](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/) buttons on the right shown and instead want the [default view](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/defaultView/) to be basicWeek.

If you aren't using that plugin...you should be.